# How to get HTML selected value and process in C?

Tags: html, c, cgi, listdir

i got a code in C that shows the list of directories in a specific path and i need to show these directories in a html select:

```
/*
 * listdir.c - Leer archivo de un directorio
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void err_quit(char *msg);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *mydirent;
    int i = 1;

    if(argc != 2) {
    //puts("USO: listdir {pathname}");
    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    argv[1]="/home/maudev";
    }

    if((dir = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
    {
    err_quit("opendir");
    }
    printf("%s%c%c\n","Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);
    printf("<TITLE>CARPETAS</TITLE>\n");
    printf("<H3>CARPETAS</H3>\n");
    printf("<select>\n");
    while((mydirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {  
        printf("\n<option value='%s'>%s",mydirent->d_name,mydirent->d_name); 
        printf("</option>\n");
    }
    printf("</select>\n");
    closedir(dir);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void err_quit(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

This is my code, by default im showing the list of directories from /home/maudev/, it shows the list of directories perfectly, but now i need to select one of these folders and show again what folders contains, and i don't know how to do that, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML part, add a `form` and submit (via POST method) the selected value:

```
printf("<form action=\"app.cgi\" method=\"post\">\n");
printf("<select>\n");
while((mydirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{  
    printf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>\n", mydirent->d_name, mydirent->d_name); 
}
printf("</select>\n");
printf("<input type=\"submit\">\n");
printf("</form>\n");
```

In the C part, read `stdin` and use the post-data value:

```
len_ = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
len = strtol(len_, NULL, 10);
postdata = malloc(len + 1);
if (!postdata) {exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
fgets(postdata, len + 1, stdin);
/* work with postdata */
free(postdata);
```

Comment: Can u show me how to do that? sorry i'm new in C programing the HTML part i understood perfectly, but i don't know how add that C code and process the selected value, i need to create a new function ? or a new class please help me

Comment: You don't need another function, and C has no classes, you just need a conditional after read the value of `"CONTENT_LENGTH"`: if len == 0 use `"/home/maudev"` else use  `postdata`.